# Bulma dropdown input field issue

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bulma

I am having an issue with a dropdown input field in my form. I am using Bulma in my Rails application. Here's the code

```
<!-- Date of birth in _form.html.erb -->

 <div class="field">
 <label class="label">Date of birth</label>
 <p class="control">
 <span class="select">
 <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, {order:[:day,:month,:year], start_year: 1975} %>
 </span>
 </p>
 </div>
```

I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see the dropdown elements (date, month and year ) are not aligned but they are collapsing into the next field input. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Dirty hack but it works like a charm:

```
<div class="select">
  <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, date_separator: '</div><div class="select">' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice hack indeed !